# real windows equivalent to cat *stdin*

Tags: cmd.exe, pipe

Under `cmd` is there a windows equivalent to the posix command `cat` ?

cat all by itself no filenames, no switches. I just want something that 
copies stdin to stdout until it hits EOF.

it's not a hard program to write, but is one provided by windows?

the answer is not necessarily a single word and is definately not type.

```
echo test | type
```

just gets me an error message

```
echo test | type con
```

hangs wainting for me to type some stuff

```
echo test | more
```

is close, but "more"` halts after one screenfull.

The reason I want this is for running a program that behaves differently when stdout is into a pipe. so I can see the output.

Comment: Can you please give a real example what exactly you want to do? For example cat file1 is just type file1; cat file1 file2 >> file3 is just type file1 file2 >> file3...

Comment: ... oh yes, cat >> file in windows is copy con >> file

Comment: Would a third party app be an acceptable option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`someprog | findstr x*` or any other single character followed by asterisk copies all lines from the pipe stdin to stdout. Specifically, it copies each line if it either does contain an `x` or doesn't, which you can easily see is always true. Windows `findstr` is roughly equivalent to Unix `grep` but with annoying minor differences in the syntax.

`findstr` is intended for text and I'm not sure (and didn't test) if it works for binary data with few or no [CR]LFs and therefore very long apparent lines. Unix `cat` with no args does work for binary, but your stated use case is programs that alter their output for pipes and in my experience that only happens on text output -- and usually is not pipes as such but rather NON-tty/NON-console/etc and therefore I can test equally well with `someprog >temp; cat temp` on Unix or `& type` on Windows unless the program is interactive and I need to see one output before entering the next input.

Comment: `x*` "zero or more x" that works. thanks. `findstr "^"` seems to work too. but either way findstr will hang if the last line does not end with CRLF. I suspect this is an _undocumented_feature_ of findstr

Comment: find seems better behaved than findstr. (the unnofficial errata for findstr is truly impressive) except it's `find /v ""` that seems to do what I want. that's got to be a bug too. but atleast it diesn't hang.  `more > con`  works too - again undocumented, but probably not a bug.

Comment: @user313114 You're right `find/v ""` is an even cleverer way I missed. Before posting I did test `findstr` with unterminated last line and it worked on (my) Vista -- but now you got me to retest on (my) Win7 and that hangs, so this may be not just an undocumented feature but an undocumented enhancement!

Comment: Very clever; update as of Windows 10: `findstr "^"` no longer hangs without a trailing line break, and apparently even the latest Win7 version has been patched; `find /v ""` still works, but is certainly counter-intuitive.

Comment: Be careful both seem to have a hidden limit of columns. On Windows 8.1 the pipe may end (no error) if a line is more than 300 or 400 chars.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: `findstr "^" > STDIN.txt` as the first line in your .bat will neatly capture all piped input for later use.

I discovered that the first line/command/program in a batch file gets STDIN so I took the following approach:

1. Capture STDIN to a file `STDIN.txt`
2. Code your .bat logic
3. Use `TYPE STDIN.txt` to access or pipe your STDIN on to further programs

### Example:

**fawk.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Capture STDIN initially as the first line of our .bat
FINDSTR "^" > STDIN.txt

:: Do some other stuff here

:: Pipe STDIN on to our program here (e.g. find all .txt files)
TYPE STDIN.txt | AWK /\.txt$/

:: Cleanup
DEL /Q STDIN.txt
```

**Usage:**

```
C:>DIR /b | fawk.bat
a.txt
file.txt
README.txt
```

Comment: Note that, because CMD (sometimes) uses `^` as an analog to ``\``,  you can abbreviate this to `findstr ^^`.

Comment: Also, ```findstr .``` and ```findstr $```  work.

Comment: Note that FINDSTR has a maximum line length of 8191 characters, and will skip any lines over this length! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman.  Only a problem if working with large inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The closest Windows equivalent to *nix's [`cat`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) is the [`TYPE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) command. Note that on *nix systems, `cat` is actually a separate program whereas Windows' `TYPE` is actually part of the command-line interpreter.

Comment: `echo test | type`  - no doesn't seem to work  if my question was unclear please improve it.

Comment: Yes, `type` overlaps with `cat` in functionality, but unlike `cat` it cannot read from _stdin_, which is what the OP is after.

Answer (score -2):

ECHO Should work similar to CAT.

Echo text into a FILE

The general syntax is

```
Echo This is some Text > FileName.txt
```

or if you want to avoid extra spaces: 
Echo Some more text>FileName.txt

Comment: no it;s nothing likr that at all,  standard input  not the xommand-line. I want tp pipe some stuff to it.

Comment: `cat` reads a file or streams's contents into the standard (like, a terminal window). `echo` just prints text into the standard output. The example you gave is using the command-line interpreter to send a program's output into a file.